# How to convey covering one's eyes from bright sunlight?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

How can I describe covering your eyes from bright sunlight?

Like putting up one of your hands over your eyebrows horizontally to prevent the sunlight coming into your eye?

Comment: Hi there! Do you want a sentence which asks someone to cover/shield their eyes or do you want to express that you shield your eyes in this way? I might have interpreted your question incorrectly and hence modified it wrong.

Comment: I wanted to express that I shield my eyes in this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a native British English speaker, I would probably say "*I shielded my eyes* from the bright sunlight".

You could be more specific if you wanted to make it absolutely clear that you did this with your hand - perhaps "*I raised my hand to shield my eyes...*" -  but there is possibly no need, as I think most people would imagine that was what was implied.

Of course, 'shielding your eyes with your hands' could mean completely covering your eyes so that you can see nothing at all. The wider context of what you say would add understanding. For example, if you said "I shielded my eyes from the bright sunlight *as I looked out to sea*" it would be quite clear you were shielding them from the light in such a way as to still see.

Comment: I spent a week in the Bristol Eye Hospital, recovering from an operation, in an all-male ward,  and I vividly remember the genial Irish nurse, who, prior to putting on the lights first thing each morning, called out, 'Gentlemen, shield your eyes!'.